# swift reflections: how to construct a new struct instance based on reflections?

Tags: swift, reflection, protocols

My example consists of:

- protocol with read-only properties
- struct implementing that protocol
- "+" operator function

I'd like the "+" **operator** to be able to **work for all implementations** of the **protocol** by creating a **new instance** of the specific type that implements that protocol.

As you can see in the source code below, the operator accepts parameters of type "Aable" (the protocol). Using the **generic placeholder T** to construct a new instance fails with the error "'Aable' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers".

Is that even possible?

Could it be achieved using reflections or some sort of introspection?

```
protocol Aable {
    var name: String { get }
}

func +(left: Aable, right: Aable) -> Aable {
    let leftType = left.dynamicType
    //error: 'Aable' cannot be constructed because 
    //       it has no accessible initializers
    return leftType(name: left.name + right.name)
}

struct A: Aable {
    let name: String
}

let a1 = A(name: "A #1")
let a2 = A(name: "A #2")

a1 + a2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You don't need `reflection` and `AableError`.

First of all lets add an `init` to your protocol

```
protocol Aable {
    var name: String { get }
    init(name:String)
}
```

Now you want a `+` operator where:

- both params conform to the protocol `Aable`
- the params have the same type
- the return type is the same of the params

You can define this constraints with generics

```
func +<T:Aable>(left: T, right: T) -> T {
    return T(name:left.name + right.name)
}
```

Now the check is performed at compile time so there's no need of the `throws`. The compiler will make sure the used values do have the proper type.

### Test #1

```
struct Box:Aable {
    let name:String
}

let amazon = Box(name: "Amazon")
let apple = Box(name: "Apple")
let res = amazon + apple
res.name // "AmazonApple"
```

### Test #2

```
struct Box:Aable {
    let name:String
}

struct Box:Aable {
    let name:String
}

struct Bottle:Aable {
    let name:String
}

let box = Box(name: "Amazon")
let bottle = Bottle(name: "Water")
box + bottle
//  ^ compile error
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly and looks very swift. I was just about to edit my question because I figured out to use generics. And now that I see it, it makes sense that the protocol needs a init method.